# Why a 2 day wait on bounty's?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on BSE, I have no clue what to do next. It is for a work project that is do in 3 days, yet I have to wait 2 days to put a bounty on it. Why is there this waiting period? I would like an answer sooner than later.

Makes no sense to me, kind of defeats the purpose of getting an answer in a timely manner (I understand a bounty doesn't guarantee an answer but it usually happens much quicker).

Thoughts!?

Comment: I was able to add a bounty this morning, within 2 hours I had an amazing answer. I feel this setting should be changed to allow bounties at any time if you have enough points.

Comment: Related question on SO meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255995/2730823